# determining column number using string in awk

Tags: bash, awk

Suppose I have a pipe separated file like:

```
|Sr|Fruits|Colors|
|1 |apple |red|
|2 |orange |orange
|3 |grapes |purple|
```

Here it is evident using `awk` that, `$2` is Fruits and `$3` is the colors column.

In future if the order of the columns change, is it possible to determine the column number using the string?

I.e *Colors* is `$3` and *Fruits* is `$2`?

Comment: For future information, with the exception of the 3rd line, your file has 5 fields, not 3. A field is defined by the field separator so `|foo|bar|` is actually 4 fields but the 1st and 4th are empty. To have two fields, you would want `foo|bar`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try:

```
$ awk -F'|' '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    if($i == "Fruits")
      printf("Column %d is Fruits\n", i-1)
    if($i == "Colors")
      printf("Column %d is Colors\n", i-1)
  }
  exit 0
}
' file
Column 2 is Fruits
Column 3 is Colors
```

A note that the actually column for *Fruits* and *Colors* are `$3` and `$4`.

Answer (score 18):

It feels a little bit clumsy but I always find the column numbers using the following line of code:

```
head -1 file | sed 's/delimiter/\n/g' | nl
```

Here I take the header row of the file and pipe it to `sed` replacing the delimiter with \n. The result is that every column header is now on a new line. Finally I pipe this to `nl` which adds row numbers which correspond to the original column numbers.

Comment: You may wish to consider a `tr` command instead of `sed`  (eg `tr '|' '\012'`) to avoid regex issues with some delimiters.

Comment: It may feel clumsy, but it's actually shorter and simpler than any other answer.

Comment: As long as you’re using `sed`, you can eliminate the `head` and do `sed 's/|/\n/g;q' file | nl` (which is even shorter). Also, consider using `nl -ba` to number the blank lines (fields).

Comment: I have now saved `sed 's/\t/\n/g;q' $1 | nl -ba` in my bin dir for as an executable `cols` file, as a useful utility.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it is better to print all the columns present in the first row, in order to check not only for these two fields, but also detecting new columns, their names, order changes, etc.

```
awk -F'|' ' { for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print i, $i; exit } ' file
```

output:

```
1
2 Sr
3 Fruits
4 Colors
5
```

Answer (score 2):

List all column headers:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="|" }
     { for(fn=1;fn<=NF;fn++) {print fn" = "$fn;}; exit; }
    ' file
```

Output:

```
$1 = 
$2 = Sr
$3 = Fruits
$4 = Colors
$5 =
```

---

Using the label-text, print the colmns of your choice, in the order you choose:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="|" }
     NR==1 { split(columns, c) 
             for(fn=1;fn<=NF;fn++) hdr[$fn]=fn; next; }
     { printf( FS ); for (text in c) printf( "%s", $hdr[c[text]]FS ); print "" }
    ' columns="Colors|Fruits" file
```

Output:

```
|red|apple |
|orange|orange |
|purple|grapes |
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to treat the field separator `|` as a record separator, and then process the first line.

In colnum.awk:

```
BEGIN {
  RS = "|" 
}
/^Fruits$|^Colors$/ {
  print $0, NR - 1
}
```

```
$ head -n1 fruits.txt | awk -f colnum.awk
Fruits 2
Colors 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tr` to convert `|` to a new line. Then calculate the line with `nl`

```
$ head -1 file.txt | tr '|' '\n' | nl
       
     1  Sr
     2  Fruits
     3  Colors
       
$
```

Comment: Unix is awesome, and so is this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
[me@mine May31TestAchive]$ cat file.csv
|Sr|Fruits|Colors|
|1 |apple |red|
|2 |orange |orange
|3 |grapes |purple|
[me@mine May31TestAchive]$ grep  -oi "^|\([a-z]*|\)\+Colors" file.csv | tr -cd "|" | wc -c
3
```

It says:

1. Return the only the part of the first matching line that goes "|" letters ...(repeats?) ..."Color".
2. Convert that output, delete everything that isn't a "|"
3. Take that output and then count the number of characters.